# Ошибка аутентификации в MongoDB при подключении к MongoLabs

Tags: mongodb

```
mongo --version => 3.0.15
mongo dsXXXXXX.mlab.com:34797/database
db.version() = 3.2.13
db.auth("login","password") => Error: 18 Authentication failed.0
```

Стоит упомянуть, что при использовании node-mongodb-native-driver выдавало ту же ошибку, решилось изменением url с `mongodb://${login}:${pass}@${user}.mlab.com:34797/${database}` на `mongodb://${login}:${pass}@${user}.mlab.com:34797/${database}?authMechanism=DEFAULT`.

Comment: задай вопрос на английском стеке

Comment: Там аккаунт создавать надо...

Comment: там можно зайти с тем же л/п что и русский